# Cannot use mono profiler - log profiler was not found

Tags: mono

I am having a strange problem using mono on linux

I have the profiler libraries in my /usr/lib folder:

```
# ls /usr/lib/libmono-profiler-*
/usr/lib/libmono-profiler-aot.so          /usr/lib/libmono-profiler-iomap.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/libmono-profiler-aot.so.0        /usr/lib/libmono-profiler-log.so
/usr/lib/libmono-profiler-aot.so.0.0.0    /usr/lib/libmono-profiler-log.so.0
/usr/lib/libmono-profiler-iomap.so        /usr/lib/libmono-profiler-log.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/libmono-profiler-iomap.so.0
```

All the permissions are **rwxrwxrwx**

However, when I try to user the profiler I get an error 
    # mono --profile=log

```
The 'log' profiler wasn't found in the main executable nor could it be loaded from 'mono-profiler-log'.
```

I cannot figure out why mono can't find the dll.

All the other mono libraries are in the same /usr/lib folder and it can find those.

Comment: did you ever resolve this